# Is there a --apple-team-id or equivalent flag for EAS Build?

Tags: expo, eas

I have access to a few developer accounts because I am an admin of them and I was wondering if it is possible to login through my main account on EAS Build then pass through a --apple-team-id ######## flag or something along those lines. And if I can include my main account on non-interactive mode that would be even better, just trying to automate a few things. For example,

```
eas build --platform ios --apple-account example@apple.com --apple-team-id ######## --non-interactive
```

Answer (score 0):

The only way I have found to do this is using the `EXPO_APPLE_TEAM_ID` environment variable ([source](https://github.com/expo/eas-cli/issues/1731#issuecomment-1468371377)):

```
EXPO_APPLE_TEAM_ID=<team-id> eas build --platform ios
```